# Distinguish private/internal github repositories in graphql query

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

I'm trying to fetch all private repositories from our organization. In the following graphql query it returns both internal and private repositories.

For `privacy` it is only possible to filter on `PRIVATE` and `PUBLIC`.
It seems there is only one field called `isPrivate`, nothing like `isInternal` as far I can see.

```
query organizationRepositories($owner: String!) {
    organization(login:$owner) {
        repositories(first: 100, privacy: PRIVATE) {
            totalCount
            nodes {
                owner {
                login
            }
            name
            id
            url
            isPrivate
        }
      }
    }
}
```

All results using above query show `isPrivate: true`, I know for a fact some of these are internal and some are private.

Is there a way to distinguish between private and internal repositories? Either by looping over the results based on some fields combo which indicates private vs internal or by querying in a different way.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a search query:

```
query {
  search(query: "org:<my-org> is:internal", type: REPOSITORY, first: 100) {
    repositoryCount
    nodes {
      ... on Repository {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For more info, see https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-for-repositories#search-by-repository-visibility

Comment: Thanks @bart-golsteijn, I will give your proposal a try soon.